# PyQt5 listen to javascript event inside QWebView to be used with python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, pyqt5, qwebkit

I have a web app inside a QWebView in a python code, this html/javascript code have a button with a click event, I would like to get that event once is triggered so it can be used for an aplicacion outside the QWebView.

tl;dr: is there a way to capture a javascript's click event to be used in the python code?

Comment: [QWebChannel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebchannel.html) and/or [QWebEngineScript](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginescript.html).

Comment: might be, I've been looking for docs about it, but there are not many examples, do you know how is any of these two options used? @ekhumoro

Comment: There are loads of examples: just search for e.g. `qwebchannel pyqt`.